# Needed to make a Loading Screen in Android

Tags: android

I am making an application and I want to design a Loading Starting interface in my aplication . 
I have an image displaying my application name. 
what I want is that I have a .gif aniamted loading icon and I want to display it on the first Screen. I have designed my first screen just I needed. Some help that it should display that .gif animated loading image and then wait for some time after that open my next activity. 
Please help me....

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Ted on this one too, but it sounds like you may just want to show a logo for some time without doing any background work. If you are looking for something that finishes based on time instead of work, check out the code below:

```
                 waitTimer = new CountDownTimer(60000, 300) {

                 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    //called every 300 milliseconds, which could be used to
                        //display some crude animation
                 }

                 public void onFinish() {
                     //After 60000 milliseconds (60 sec) finish current 
                         //activity and open next activity           
                 }
              }.start();
```

But Ted has the correct answer for a true loading screen that finishes after work has been completed.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a job for `AsyncTask`. You implement a `doInBackground` method to do whatever setup you want and wait until the user has read your promo (er, loading) screen. In `onPostExecute` (which runs on the UI thread), start your app's main activity and finish() the loading screen.

Answer (score 0):

Just on the other note, Android doesn't support .gif animations. You'll have to use ProgressDialog instead.

Rest, as an answer, I'll go with what Ted has said.