# Trying to add splash screen

Tags: android, splash-screen

I have been trying to add splash screen like [this one](http://web.archive.org/web/20130712051340/http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/) in my android app but the app keeps crashing whenever i try to run it. here are the codes

**activity_splash.xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Splash"
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:background="@drawable/cricket"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="Splash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

Here is my java code for splash activity
**Splash.java**

```
    public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Splash screen timer
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler() {
            public void postDelayed(Runnable runnable, int splashTimeOut) {
            }

            @Override
            public void close() {

            }

            @Override
            public void flush() {

            }

            @Override
            public void publish(LogRecord record) {

            }
        }.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
             * want to show case your app logo / company
             */

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity
                Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }

}
```

Comment: you imported the wrong Handler

Comment: Please try this solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994112/how-to-display-a-welcome-screen-in-android

Comment: I have refereed to this link... and the splash screen started showing too but as soon as the splashscreen stops...rather then starting the main activity the app crashes...

Answer (score 1):

update your handler

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
}
```

Comment: what does make that difference to call in `onPause` why not in `Handler`

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    // Splash screen timer
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
             * want to show case your app logo / company
             */

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
```

}

Comment: Vivek the code is working.. and the splash screen started showing too but as soon as the splashscreen stops...rather then starting the main activity the app crashes

Comment: Please include a brief explanation of what your code does when you answer a question with a code snippet.

Comment: Check whether you are passing your Intent properly or not.Refer this [Demo Code](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2)

Comment: It is implemented properly but the name of the application changes to splash.....What is the solution for this?